Можно ли запустить Chromium от BAS с помощью Puppeteer?
Есть open source проект BAS, предназначен для автоматизации браузера. Там используется Chromium, вопрос заключается в том, могу ли я каким либо образом использовать тот браузер, что используют они с Puppeteer. Я попробовал сделать это:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: "D:/chromium/chrome/worker.exe",
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
      "--no-proxy-server",
      "--force-device-scale-factor=1",
      "--fake-variations-channel=stable",
      "--variations-override-country=us",
      "--noerrdialogs",
      "--window-position=0,0",
      "--disable-smooth-scrolling",
      "--disable-auto-reload",
      "--disable-features=GpuProcessHighPriorityWin,GpuUseDisplayThreadPriority",
      "--disable-gpu-program-cache",
      "--disable-gpu-shader-disk-cache",
      "--disk-cache-size=1",
      "--lang=en",
      "--window-size=1040,694",
      "--enable-privacy-sandbox-ads-apis",
      // Добавьте любые другие параметры, которые могут быть необходимы
    ],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://google.com");

  await page.screenshot({
    path: "screenshot.jpg",
  });

  // Ожидание 100 секунд, чтобы вы могли увидеть браузер
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100000));

  await browser.close();
})();

Сам браузер запускается, код работает, но UI браузера не виден, будто бы он запущен в headless режиме, хотя это не так. Браузер 100% работает, я пробовал с разными сайтами, скриншот действительно делается, почему я не вижу интерфейс браузера при запуске?
